# Can custom JavaDoc tags be required?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, tags, javadoc

In Android Studio it is possible to run the inspection "Declaration has JavaDoc problems" and select some "Required Tags".
It allows also to add additional JavaDoc tags, but is there a way to make them required?

Thank you very much for any help!

Example:
If "verifiedBy" tag is added, it seems that there is no way to set it as required.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Pleaes report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand.. Do you mean that it should "automatically" be required? @y.bedrov

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's a missing feature. And you could report a request on YouTrack to add it.

Comment: Ok, thanks @y.bedrov